# Java URL with Socks4 Proxy

Tags: java, sockets, url, socks, proxies

My problem is that i can't use Socks4 Proxies with urls because of the bug in java.
It will just give me the malformed reply from socks server exeption.

What i've tried:

`URL url = new URL("https://google.com");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection(p);`

i've tried it with several proxies to make sure the proxy is not dead.

Sorry for my bad english :D.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how can i make it work that urlconnections don't give me a 'malformed reply from socks server' exception when i use Socks4 proxies